# Determine all $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $a^3-8a^2-14a+144$ is prime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Here is a problem from my teacher.

I'm not sure there is no typo.

> Determine all $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $a^3-8a^2-14a+144$ is prime.

I found that $a$ must in form $6k+5$,but had nothing to do next.

I tried to factor it while failed.

Comment: When $a=11$ the expression is prime. And I think the same happens for $23$.

Comment: there is an infinity of solution :-1
11,23,59,....

Comment: @Amine proof? :)

Comment: @ViniciusM. Dirichlet's theorem of  arithmetic progression ensuring that there is infinitely many primes of the form $6k+5$

Comment: @Amine, Dirichlet's thm asserts that there are infinitely many primes in the sequence $6k+5$, op asked for primes of the form $a^3+...$ and said (did not check it) that $a$ must be of the form $6k+5$. I don't see how you can apply Dirichlet's thm here. Can you clarify a little bit, please?

Comment: it is not surjective on the numbers of the form of $6k+5$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly suspect a typo.

Let $f(x)=x^3-8x^2-14x+144$.

1. $f(x)$ has leading coefficient $1$, which is positive.
2. $f(x)$ has no integer roots, hence irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.
3. $f(5)=-1$ so $\gcd(f(1), f(2), \ldots)=1$.

Now $f(x)$ satisfies the conditions of [Bunyakovsky's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture). To my knowledge, it remains unproved for polynomials with degree $>1$. (The degree $1$ case corresponds to Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions)

Comment: +1. I was editing my answer to add Bunyakovsky's conjecture.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of them supposedly infinite. There is an open problem, known as [Bunyakovsky conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture), which is related to this. If $p(a)$ is an irreducible polynomial, with no trivial factors, then there exists infinite $a$'s such that $p(a)$ is a prime.
Here are the ones within the first $2000$ values of $a$.
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
a & a^3-8a^2-14a+144\\
\hline
11 & 353 \\ 23 & 7757 \\ 
59 & 176849 \\ 
65 & 240059 \\ 
89 & 640499 \\ 
101 & 947423 \\ 
125 & 1826519 \\ 
149 & 3128399 \\ 
161 & 3963803 \\ 
191 & 6673493 \\ 
215 & 9565709 \\ 
227 & 11281817 \\ 
233 & 12211907 \\ 
239 & 13191749 \\ 
245 & 14222639 \\ 
275 & 20188169 \\ 
281 & 21552563 \\ 
305 & 27624299 \\ 
323 & 32859257 \\ 
371 & 49958633 \\ 
377 & 52440467 \\ 
389 & 57647999 \\ 
407 & 66088397 \\ 
413 & 69074807 \\ 
419 & 72149849 \\ 
473 & 104027507 \\ 
479 & 108060149 \\ 
491 & 116435393 \\ 
527 & 144134117 \\ 
533 & 149139407 \\ 
539 & 154259249 \\ 
545 & 159494939 \\ 
557 & 170319047 \\ 
563 & 175910057 \\ 
593 & 205706507 \\ 
617 & 231831107 \\ 
677 & 306612767 \\ 
701 & 340531223 \\ 
749 & 415691399 \\ 
773 & 457099007 \\ 
785 & 478795979 \\ 
833 & 572446907 \\ 
869 & 650181599 \\ 
887 & 691557677 \\ 
923 & 779502257 \\ 
947 & 842090537 \\ 
971 & 907942433 \\ 
989 & 959522999 \\ 
995 & 977140889 \\ 
1007 & 1013020997 \\ 
1055 & 1165322549 \\ 
1061 & 1185369503 \\ 
1145 & 1490619539 \\ 
1151 & 1514231573 \\ 
1187 & 1661157977 \\ 
1235 & 1871433929 \\ 
1271 & 2040284333 \\ 
1283 & 2098745657 \\ 
1301 & 2188515023 \\ 
1343 & 2407852757 \\ 
1349 & 2440334399 \\ 
1355 & 2473106849 \\ 
1361 & 2506171403 \\ 
1367 & 2539529357 \\ 
1445 & 3000471839 \\ 
1457 & 3075987947 \\ 
1463 & 3114216557 \\ 
1469 & 3152760599 \\ 
1493 & 3310117007 \\ 
1511 & 3431509853 \\ 
1583 & 3946753157 \\ 
1601 & 4083156923 \\ 
1607 & 4129313597 \\ 
1649 & 4462185899 \\ 
1685 & 4761356879 \\ 
1715 & 5020647209 \\ 
1721 & 5073609683 \\ 
1757 & 5399224247 \\ 
1775 & 5567129669 \\ 
1781 & 5623862063 \\ 
1817 & 5972368307 \\ 
1823 & 6031816757 \\ 
1859 & 6396809849 \\ 
1871 & 6521668133 \\ 
1913 & 6971452307 \\ 
1925 & 7103656319 \\ 
1937 & 7237521227 \\ 
1955 & 7441455449 \\ 
1973 & 7649185007 \\ 
1997 & 7932122087 \\
\hline
\end{array}